# How to export an fbx skeleton animation?

Tags: export, .fbx, rigify

I am failing over and over again, trying to export an fbx skeleton animation from Blender.
I am using a Mocap program that spits out a very basic animated rig. I've never used Blender before and have followed various tutorials for two days, trying to get this thing exported.

[image: screenshot]

I try to follow these steps
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ysl0qYq5p9w&ab_channel=RoyalSkies

Everything I do, either the file exported is a tiny file size and doesn't work, or Blender just says (NotResponding) and hangs infinitely.
Please could someone break it down for me, in the most simple, simple, simple, beginner steps, like I am a 5 year old, how to do this?

I'm not sure if I'm just selecting the wrong things or do I need to "BAKE" the animation first? I just don't understand

The sample file is here, if that helps:
https://we.tl/t-IiwQUJQFVX

Thanks so much

Comment: Hello and welcome. Please briefly describe what you trying to do in your blend file. The  Mocap program has created this file? There is an animated stick figure floating around with a Rigify metarig, 4 video(?) planes, and a bunch of empties (for the mocap data?).

Comment: Hi, @Blunder Thanks for responding. What I am trying to do is export an fbx of some Mocap data out of Blender and use it in Maya. This file is from an open source mocap software that is currently in development. This is the file exactly as it is currently exporting from the software. I am not familiar with Blender but wish to generate an fbx of the bone animation for use in Maya. I need only the bone animation, to drive a control rig, similar to the way I would use the exported data from Mixamo, or Plask. I currently cannot work out how to export successfully and wanted guidance. Thanks.

Comment: Oh okay. It looks a bit strange (the orientation, the animation, all these empties...?) Maybe someone else knows? Can't you just import the mocap data into Blender or Maya? [Blender can import bvh data](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/addons/import_export/anim_bvh.html). Usually, the imported data is an armature (skeleton) that can be used for animation or for retargetting to use your own armature. (I guess these empties are for retargetting, kinda.)

Answer (score 0):

There are gaps or "holes" in your animation making it impossible for Blender to successfully prepare an fbx file. For one, the metarig is completely missing from frames 1 to 26 and again from frames 300 to 325. It needs to be present in all frames especially since it is parenting the stick figure mesh. Secondly, within the metarig itself, certain bones, for example hand/finger bones - are present in some frames and completely absent in others. The right-hand bones appear in frame 66 disjoint at 70, vanish at 85 then reappear later etc. You need to provide Blender a neat, complete metarig and animation to work with especially given the length of your animation and the fact that there are additional hand and finger bones.